# Yocto bitbake .bbappend not installing file

Tags: yocto, recipe

I am trying to add a json to /etc on a device.
Have read many SO answers and not found a solution.
The new json is called audio_config.json, it is under files/ in the same directory as the .bbappend. Am using append because this file is needed only on one device model while the main recipe is on many models.

Doing this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://audio_config.json"

do_install_append() {
   install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
   install -m 644 ${B}/audio_config.json ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

Gets an error saying that the json is not in the work directory.
The same thing happens if I use ${WORKDIR} instead of ${B}.
Other recipes in this tree follow this same model, not sure what the problem is.

If I use ${THISDIR} then it says that the json is not located in the base recipe directory - which it's not supposed to be.

From SO posts I have tried

```
FILES_${PN}-audio_config.json = "${sysconfdir}/audio_config.json"
```

But that seems to have no effect.

TIA!

Comment: Is it `xraudio_config.json` or `audio_config.json`? Cause your install seems to do `install -m 644 ${B}/xraudio_config.json ${D}${sysconfdir}`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: If the `audio_config.json` is located at `${RECIPE_APPEND_DIR}/files/audio_config.json`, it should be able to find it, and then you should be able to do `install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/audio_config.json ${D}${sysconfdir}`

Comment: Did you try to debug verifying both SRC_URI and FILESEXTRAPATHS using bbdebug ? You can also use devshell task to ensure file is present in working path ?

Answer (score 1):

In `do_unpack()` the file is copied to `${WORKDIR}`, not `${B}` (build dir) and not `${S}` (sources dir). This recipe works for me with Yocto Dunfell:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://audio_config.json"

do_install_append() {
   install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
   install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/audio_config.json ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

Note the different source path argument in the second call to `install`.

I'm guessing that there was a yocto/bitbake bug that affected you.

Answer (score 0):

According to users and documentation, what I had above should have worked.  But it didn't.
What did work was this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
AUDIO_CONFIG_FILES := "${THISDIR}/files"

do_install_append() {
   install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
   install -m 644 ${AUDIO_CONFIG_FILES}/audio_config.json ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

Using a variable for immediate expansion of $THISDIR set the local path correctly and the install occurs.

Comment: Check where the file `audio_config.json` is located first. You should use something like `${S}/audio_config.json` instead of `${AUDIO_CONFIG_FILES}/audio_config.json`. `S` is probably defined in bb recipes file

Comment: audio_config.json is located in files/ under the directory where the .bbappend is.
${S} is the source directory for the component that may or may not need the json, so I couldn't put it there.

Comment: I have never saw THISDIR being used in installation process. Because the search path which is used when looking for files, has been extended, I would have added json file to the extracted src files before moving it to the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

You were right to add the FILES_${PN} to add the file to the image. But do not add any suffix to it, just append your file to the variable:

```
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/audio_config.json"
```

Also, you should use the `${WORKDIR}` in your install.

```
install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/audio_config.json ${D}${sysconfdir}
```

Also check the work directory of your package to get some logs and see the files actually retrieved for an easier debugging.